# Why do I get 'Undeclared identifier' when specifying a runtime color in a FireMonkey Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I'm playing with my first FireMonkey app. I've created a grid of TRectangle's and now I want to set the color of each one programmatically. I've done:

```
procedure TForm9.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  C : TRectangle;
  I : integer;
//const
//  Alpha = TAlphaColor($FF000000);
//  Red = Alpha or TAlphaColor($FF0000);

begin
  for I := 0 to ScaledLayout1.ChildrenCount-1 do
    begin
    If ScaledLayout1.Children[I] is TRectangle then
      begin
      C := Trectangle(ScaledLayout1.Children[I]);
      C.Fill.Color := Red; <<< ERROR
      C.Fill.Kind := bkSolid <<< ERROR;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

I get compiler errors `'unidentified identifier'` at '<< ERROR' trying to assign the constants 'Red' and 'bkSolid'. If I go into System.UITypes and copy out 'Red' as in my commented out 'const' above, it all works. Yet 'System.UITypes' is in my uses list. Trying `C.Fill.Color := TAlphaColor.Red` does not work either. What might I be doing wrong please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TAlphaColor is type of cardinal, not an enum or const.
TAlphaColors.Red is working (note the 's' by AlphaColorS) or claRed.
By bkSolid use TBrushKind.bkSolid

Comment: Thanks Arjen. It was a combination of ENUMTYPES then (I'd not come across this before) and finger trouble. Thanks.

Comment: The new `TEnumType.etThing` style is confusing for old timers, ain't it?  personally I think that the "bk" prefix in TBrushKind is wrong. Either use the new syntax (Type and dot followed by a word) without prefixes, or use prefixes but not the new enum syntax. Combining them is silly. But then this is Embarcadero that did this, so we're stuck with silly.

Answer (score 1):

in the uses clause insert

uses 
   `System.UIConsts`

and then use `ClaRed` instead of red
             `clawhite` instead of white and so on ..

and `TBrushKind.bkSolid` instead of `bksolid`